# BlockingQueue - blocked drainTo() methods

Tags: java, concurrency

BlockingQueue has the method called drainTo() but it is not blocked.  I need a queue that I want to block but also able to retrieve queued objects in a single method.

```
Object first = blockingQueue.take();

if ( blockingQueue.size() > 0 )
    blockingQueue.drainTo( list );
```

I guess the above code will work but I'm looking for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Are you referring to the comment in the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo(java.util.Collection)):

> Further, the behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection
>   is modified while the operation is in progress.

I believe that this refers to the collection `list` in your example:

```
blockingQueue.drainTo(list);
```

meaning that you cannot modify `list` at the same time you are draining from `blockingQueue` into `list`.  However, the blocking queue internally synchronizes so that when `drainTo` is called, <strike>puts and</strike> (see note below) gets will block.  If it did not do this, then it would not be truly Thread-safe.  You can look at the source code and verify that `drainTo` is Thread-safe regarding the blocking queue itself.

Alternately, do you mean that when you call `drainTo` that you want it to block until at least one object has been added to the queue?  In that case, you have little choice other than:

```
list.add(blockingQueue.take());
blockingQueue.drainTo(list);
```

to block until one or more items have been added, and then drain the entire queue into the collection `list`.

Note: As of Java 7, a separate lock is used for gets and puts. Put operations are now permitted during a drainTo (and a number of other take operations).

Comment: It's unlikely that the collection you are copying to would be thread-safe. What would be the point?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that drainTo(list) won't call list.clear()? I don't see that in the javadoc anywhere.

Comment: @Recurse:  The JavaDoc doesn't *guarantee* that drainTo(list) won't call clear(), I suppose, because it doesn't say it won't do so.  However, it would be very surprising if it did something so major to a collection passed to it without documenting this action.  Many would consider this to be a serious bug.

Comment: @Eddie I updated to reflect the nature of the changes added since Java 7. Feel free to revise the answer as necessary.

Comment: The javadoc contract of `.drainTo()` is a little ambiguous (as most natural language contracts will be) but "all available elements" would suggest non-blocking. I've confirmed this for the Android SDK implementation of Array and List blocking queues.

Comment: @corsiKa, I'm struggling to understand this counterintuitive statement: "Put operations are now permitted during a drainTo (and a number of other take operations).". Isn't allowing a consumer to block waiting for a message while a producer puts a message onto the queue _the very point_ of a `BlockingQueue`? Why would Java 6 have a blockingqueue that didn't support this? Can you help me understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: @bacar: Although corsiKa said this is a Java 7 change, I don't see where in the JavaDoc it is guaranteed that gets and puts use a separate lock.  It may be that the JVM implementing classes all happen to do so, but I don't see where this is guaranteed.  Anyway, `drainTo` isn't itself a blocking operation.  It returns what happens to be in the queue right now.  Blocking queues do offer operations that block as you say, but `drainTo` isn't one of them.  Because of that, there's no point in explicitly blocking puts during a `drainTo`, unless you need to do so to guarantee consistency.

Comment: It's the fact that 'take operations' were also mentioned, that is confusing me. If I can't `put()` while I `take()`, a BlockingQueue seems useless!

Comment: bacar: Given, as you say, that a blocking queue must be able to do a put while a take is blocking, I took @corsiKa's edit to mean that you could now do a put during the **non-blocking** type take operations.  We need corsiKa to clarify on that point if something different is meant.

Answer (score 20):

If you happen to use Google Guava, there's a nifty [`Queues.drain()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html#drain-java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue-java.util.Collection-int-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method.

> Drains the queue as `BlockingQueue.drainTo(Collection, int)`, but if the
>   requested `numElements` elements are not available, it will wait for
>   them up to the specified timeout.

Answer (score 10):

I found this pattern useful.

```
List<byte[]> blobs = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
if (queue.drainTo(blobs, batch) == 0) {
   blobs.add(queue.take());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the API available, I don't think you are going to get much more elegant. Other than you can remove the size test.

If you are wanting to atomically retrieve a contiguous sequence of elements even if another removal operation coincides, I don't believe even `drainTo` guarantees that.

Comment: drainTo definitely blocks any put, get, take, etc...  Check the source code.  This API is thread-safe against other calls to the blocking queue.  However, if the Collection to which you are draining changes during drainTo, you can have a problem.

Comment: OK, true, funny, but besides the point.  Check the implementing classes in the JDK.  (Which is clearly what I meant.)

Comment: They are not the only possible implementation classes. For instance, I'm sure it is relatively straightforward(!) to convert ConcurrentLinkedQueue to a "ConcurrentLinkedBlockingQueue" (although clearly the blocking operations would not be wait-free).

Answer (score -1):

Source code:

```
 596:     public int drainTo(Collection<? super E> c) {
              //arg. check
 603:         lock.lock();
 604:         try {
 608:             for (n = 0 ; n != count ; n++) {
 609:                 c.add(items[n]);
 613:             }
 614:             if (n > 0) {
 618:                 notFull.signalAll();
 619:             }
 620:             return n;
 621:         } finally {
 622:             lock.unlock();
 623:         }
 624:     }
```

ArrayBlockingQueue is eager to return 0. BTW, it could do it before taking the lock.

Comment: No. Taking the lock doesn't just provide for mutual exclusion, it also makes sure the count seen is "fresh", that updates to main memory from other threads are seen. You could make "count" volatile, but volatile writes are relatively slow so writing would mean both holding lock + volatile write, probably more total overhead. IMHO any developer writing concurrent code should attempt to do his/her best to understand the java memory model: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4