# Block before draining ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: java, concurrency

I find myself repeating this pattern and have often wondered if it is idiomatic in Java or there is a better way of achieving this behaviour.

Problem: Given a producer/consumer setup, the consumer wants to process batches of items, so it uses `drainTo()`, however `drainTo()` will poll for existing items and possibly fail to get any items, to avoid this I prefix the drain with a `take()` to ensure it blocks until at least one item is available.

One problem I get, with a particular dataset, is with many use cases that the batch size is often irregular alternating between (1, N, 1, N). In general is this a common way to solve this problem:

Example:

```
 ArrayBlockingQueue<Foo> queue;

 function void produce() {
    while(true) {
       queue.put(createFoo());
    }
 }

 function void consumeBatchSpin() {
    while(true) {
       List<Foo> batch = Lists.newLinkedList();
       queue.drainTo(batch);

       doSomething(batch);
       //the problem here is that if nothing is being produced, this loop will spin
    }
 }

 function void consumeBatchTake() {
    while(true) {
       List<Foo> batch = Lists.newLinkedList();
       batch.add(queue.take()); //force at least one item to be there
       queue.drainTo(batch);

       doSomething(batch);
    }
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/831861/139010 and http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2006-July/002901.html so yes, this seems like a not-entirely-uncommon solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding to a list and taking the **whole** list on get.

I have posted one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15135308/823393) recently. It is undergoing code review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/23275/11913) but my tests suggest it is robust.

Essentially, when you do a put you add your new element to the current list. When you do a get you get the **whole** list and atomically replace it with a new empty one.

No need to use `drainTo` and no spinning at all.